# Cannot import modules when using jest jsdom environment

Tags: javascript, jestjs

My problem is that, when I use the jsdom environment, the tests won't run, it says that I can't import outside a module.

I have tried using the default environment (node), but some tests won't work because I'm using 'window' and 'document' functions, and it will throw an error saying "document is not defined."

Does somebody knows someway to make it work?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: Node is "JavaScript on the server," so you won't be able to reference `window` and `document` objects, since those are only present when executing JS in the browser/on the client.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.